# Android SDK were not found in specified location in Appcelerator studio

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have tried everything I could find on web, but nothing works.

> 1) Restart Appcelerator studio
>
> 2) Delete config.json file in .titanium folder
>
> 3) Updated all android API using android sdk manager

I cannot install adnroid sdk in `C:` because I do not have enough space there, I have everything on `E drive`, used to work without problem.

> Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 5.0.9, Titanium SDK
>   version 7.4.0.GA Copyright (c) 2012-2015, Appcelerator, Inc.  All
>   Rights Reserved.
>
> Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/
>
> Enter ctrl-c at any time to quit.
>
> ──────────────────┤ Check Environment ├───────────────────
>
> Node.js   ?  node               installed (v8.12.0)   ?  npm
>   installed (v6.4.1)
>
> Titanium CLI   *  cli                new version v5.2.0 available
>   (currently v5.0.9)
>
> Titanium CLI Dependencies   ?  async              up-to-date (v1.4.2) 
>   ?  colors             up-to-date (v1.1.2)   ?  fields
>   up-to-date (v0.1.24)   ?  humanize           up-to-date (v0.0.9)   ? 
>   longjohn           up-to-date (v0.2.9)   ?  moment
>   up-to-date (v2.10.6)   ?  node-appc          up-to-date (v0.2.31)   ? 
>   request            up-to-date (v2.62.0)   ?  semver
>   up-to-date (v5.0.3)   ?  sprintf            up-to-date (v0.1.5)   ? 
>   temp               up-to-date (v0.8.3)   ?  winston
>   up-to-date (v1.0.2)   ?  wrench             up-to-date (v1.5.8)
>
> Titanium SDK   ?  latest sdk         installed (v7.4.0.GA)   × 
>   selected sdk       selected Titanium SDK "vundefined" is not installed
>
> Android Environment   !  sdk                Android SDK not found   ! 
>   targets            no targets found   !  avds               no avds
>   found   !  ndk                Android NDK not found
>
> Java Development Kit   ?  jdk                installed (v1.8.0)   ? 
>   java               installed C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe   ?  javac              installed
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javac.exe   ?  keytool
>   installed C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\keytool.exe   ? 
>   jarsigner          installed C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\jarsigner.exe
>
> IntelR Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)   ?  compatible
>   ?  installed
>
> Network   ?  online
>     -  no proxy server configured   ×  https://www.google.com (HTTP status: 404) is unreachable   ×  http://developer.appcelerator.com
>   (HTTP status: 404) is unreachable   ?  Java-based connection test

Answer (score 0):

You have the selected titanium sdk set to vundefined here "Titanium SDK ? latest sdk installed (v7.4.0.GA) × selected sdk selected Titanium SDK "vundefined" is not installed" use this command in terminal: `sdk appc ti sdk select 6.3.0.GA`

if you are still getting an error after this use this command in terminal to setup Android: `appc titanium setup android`

Answer (score -1):

Chech `appc ti config`. You can set your SDK folder with

```
appc ti config android.sdkPath /your/path
appc ti config android.ndkPath /your/path
```